# Problem with Python scraping script using Laravel 10

Tags: python, web-scraping, laravel-10

I'm trying to run a python script which makes a scraping.

```
""" Scraping Selenium"""

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# Para esperar por elementos en selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# Para condiciones en selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# Excepcion de timeout en selenium
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

import time
import sys


def iniciar_chrome():
    """ Funcion para iniciar chrome"""

    # OPCIONES DE CHROME
    options = Options()
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
#    options.add_argument('--headless')  # Ejecuta chrome sin abrir la ventana
    # Modifica el tamaño de la ventana
    options.add_argument("--window-size=970,1080")
    # Desactiva las notificaciones
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    # Desactiva la política de Same Origin Policy
    options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")  # Desactiva las extensiones
    # Desactiva las notificaciones
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    # Ignora los errores de certificados
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Desactiva el sandbox
    options.add_argument("--log-level=3")  # Modifica el nivel de registro
    # Permite ejecutar contenido inseguro
    options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    # Desactiva la comprobación de navegador por defecto
    options.add_argument("--no-default-browser-check")
    options.add_argument("--no-first-run")  # Desactiva la primera ejecución
    options.add_argument("--no-proxy-server")  # Desactiva el servidor de proxy
    # Evita que selenium sea detectado
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

    # PARAMETROS A OMITIR EN EL INICIO DE CHROMEDRIVER

    exp_opt = [
        'enable-automation',
        'enable-logging',
        'ignore-certificate-errors',
        'enable-logging',
    ]
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', exp_opt)

    # PARAMETROS QUE DEFINEN PREFERENCIAS EN CHROMEDRIVER

    prefs = {
        # notificaciones 0=preguntar, 1=si, 2=no
        'profile.default_content_setting_values': 2,
        # Define el idioma del navegador
        'intl.accept_languages': ['es-ES', 'es'],
        # Evita que Chrome nos pregunte si queremos guardar contraseña al loguear
        'credentials_enable_service': False,
    }

    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(
        ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

    # Posiciona la ventana de Chrome en la esquina superior izquierda
    driver.set_window_position(0, 0)

    return driver


def obtener_facturas():
    """ Funcion para iniciar sesion en instagram"""
    # argumento = sys.argv[2]
    driver.get("https://sucursalvirtual.cge.cl/detalle-de-boleta")

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'clientId')))

    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'clientId').send_keys('9002375')

    driver.switch_to.frame(0)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]').click()

    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    time.sleep(2)

    driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//*[@id="portlet_com_liferay_client_extension_web_internal_portlet_ClientExtensionEntryPortlet_38501_45326"]/div/div/div/remote-app/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/button').click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = iniciar_chrome()

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # tiempo de espera
    res = obtener_facturas()
    input("Presiona enter para cerrar")
    driver.quit()
```

The script works all good alone. But when I try to run it with Laravel it throws me this error:

```
The command "C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\Dev\PHP\Laravel\GOGODEV-1\crud\public\cge.py 9002375" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\Dev\PHP\Laravel\GOGODEV-1\crud\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ "powershell" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. "powershell" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\Dev\PHP\Laravel\GOGODEV-1\crud\public\cge.py", line 104, in <module> driver = iniciar_chrome() ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\Dev\PHP\Laravel\GOGODEV-1\crud\public\cge.py", line 74, in iniciar_chrome ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 40, in install driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 40, in _get_driver_binary_path file = self._download_manager.download_file(driver.get_driver_download_url(os_type)) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\drivers\chrome.py", line 32, in get_driver_download_url driver_version_to_download = self.get_driver_version_to_download() ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\driver.py", line 48, in get_driver_version_to_download return self.get_latest_release_version() ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Pablo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\drivers\chrome.py", line 64, in get_latest_release_version determined_browser_version = ".".join(determined_browser_version.split(".")[:3]) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

This is my Laravel controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class FacturaController extends Controller {
    public function facturas(Request $request) {
        $numero_cuenta = $request->numero_cuenta;
        $pythonPath = "C:\\Users\\Pablo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe";
        $scriptPath = base_path('\public\cge.py');
        $process = new Process([$pythonPath, $scriptPath, $numero_cuenta]);
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }

        return redirect('/formulario')->with('success', 'Operación completada con éxito');
    }
}
```

I think it's related to the execution of webdriverchromeManager but I'm not sure.

I've tried adding the PowerShell to the path, or executing the script in PowerShell like this:

```
$command = [
    'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe',
    'C:\\Users\\Pablo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe',
    'C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\Dev\\PHP\\Laravel\\GOGODEV-1\\crud\\public\\cge.py',
    $numero_cuenta
];

$process = new Process($command);
$process->run();
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Your problem is a Python problem `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`. That error is not caused by Laravel. If the Python program works without Laravel being involved, then you have a Python installation/environment/user problem.